# CDI: manual creating beans with constructor arguments

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I have a class which I want to be a bean

```
public class SomeBean{
   public SomeBean(){
     //default constructor
   }
   public SomeBean(String someStr){
    //constructor with arguments.
   }
}
```

In order to create manually CDI bean I do the following

```
Bean<?> bean = (Bean<?>) beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(SomeBean.class));
SomeBean someBean =(SomeBean) beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
```

However the above method will create SomeBean instance wth default constructor. How can I create bean and pass String argument to construcot?
P.S. CDI - WELD

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to define beans with given constructor arguments is via a **producer method**, e.g.

```
@Produces @ApplicationScoped @MyQualifier
public SomeBean myBean() {
    return new SomeBean("foo");
}
```

Application code should not normally have to use the `BeanManager`, unless you want to create a CDI extension.

Comment: I know about produces and understand you. But I need for my situation manual creating.